# CTreeCtrl - only use checkboxes for certain rows/children

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc, tree

I have a CTreeCtrl and I filled it with content. Now I wanted to add checkboxes but JUST for certain ones. I've found the possibilty to activate checkboxes on the TreeCtrl with `m_Tree.ModifyStyle(0, TVS_CHECKBOXES)`, but this adds a checkbox on each node/child on the whole Ctrl. Is it possible to turn this feature on, but just for certain ones?

All I found is the possibility to add three different pictures, catch the clickevent on a node and change the image. Is there an easier way? Let me know.

Thanks a lot,
jntme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that CTreeCtrl provide any method to add check boxes at specified node only.
Easiest way to do this is explain in following link.

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/2005-10/msg00454.html.

please go through and let me know if you are facing problem.

Comment: I found that site too - but this is exactly what I try to avoid. In the meantime I don't think that there is an other possibility :/

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish what you want with a custom draw tree control.  But, you'll need to render the image states yourself.  That could get messy because you'll need to account for all of the possible different states.

Comment: like I said - I search a way to avoid that method. But I'm gently facing the reality that there is no easier way to do this...